# Fix Error in Form when Select field options trigger another select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, triggers

I have the following Select fields and some input fields.

[jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/6](http://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/6)

The select field [id="subject"] is the **PARENT**. When the value "Order Related" is selected, it triggers a select field [id="OrderRelatedSelect"] and the text field [id="OrderNo"].

This [id="OrderRelatedSelect"] further triggers some other fields. When the value "ReturnExchange" is selected, one Text field [id="ProductCode"] and a **Select Field [id="ReturnTypeSelect"]** is triggered.

**This is where the problem is.** Once the value "ReturnExchange" gets selected, even if we change the option value of the **PARENT** Select field, this select field [id="ReturnTypeSelect"] shows up in all the other **PARENT** options. It can only be disabled when we revert back to Order Selected and Change the value of the [id="OrderRelatedSelect"] to something else. How can I fix this so that this [id="ReturnTypeSelect"] only shows when the **PARENT** option value is "Order Related".

This is the code I'm using -

```
<select id="subject" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Subject</option>
        <option value="Order Related">Order Related</option>
        <option value="Product Related">Product Related</option>
        <option value="Store Related">Store Related</option>
        <option value="Media Related">Media Related</option>
        <option value="Kollab Requests">Kollab Requests</option>
        <option value="Other Inquiry">Other Inquiry</option>
    </select>

        <select id="OrderRelatedSelect" style="display:none" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Subject</option>
        <option value="OrderStatus">Order Status</option>
        <option value="ReturnExchange">Request a Return/Exchange</option>
        <option value="Store Related">Shipping Information</option>
        </select>

        <input type="text" id="OrderNo" placeholder="Enter Order #" style="display:none" required="required">
        <input type="text" id="ProductCode" placeholder="Enter Product Code (Separate multiple products with commas)" style="display:none" required="required">
        <input type="text" id="OtherInquiry" placeholder="Enter Subject" style="display:none" required="required">

        <select id="ReturnTypeSelect" style="display:none" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a Return Type</option>
        <option value="Refund">Refund</option>
        <option value="Exchange">Exchange</option>
        </select>

      <script>
        $('#subject').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#OrderRelatedSelect").toggle($(this).val()=="Order Related");
  $("#OrderNo").toggle($(this).val()=="Order Related");
  $("#ProductCode").toggle($(this).val()=="Product Related");
  $("#OtherInquiry").toggle($(this).val()=="Other Inquiry");
        });

        $('#OrderRelatedSelect').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#ProductCode").toggle($(this).val()=="ReturnExchange");
  $("#ReturnTypeSelect").toggle($(this).val()=="ReturnExchange");
        });

      </script>
```

**EDIT : Modified Code**

This is the Script that I run now instead of what's above. Nested a toggle off inside.the OrderRelatedSelect onchange function.

```
<script>
        $('#subject').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#OrderRelatedSelect").toggle($(this).val()=="Order Related");
  $("#OrderNo").toggle($(this).val()=="Order Related");
  $("#ProductCode").toggle($(this).val()=="Product Related");
  $("#OtherInquiry").toggle($(this).val()=="Other Inquiry");
        });

        $('#OrderRelatedSelect').on('change',function(){
  var selection = $(this).val(); 
  console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
  $("#ProductCode").toggle($(this).val()=="ReturnExchange");
  $("#ReturnTypeSelect").toggle($(this).val()=="ReturnExchange");

          // Toggle off ReturnTypeSelect
          $('#subject').on('change',function(){
    var selection = $(this).val(); 
    console.log("Detected change..." + selection);
    $("#ReturnTypeSelect").toggle($(this).val()=="Order Related");
          });
        });

      </script>
```

Comment: Umm is it just me or is this really confusing?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - Damn I tried my best to explain clearly, because it is slightly complex. Which is why I mention the ids again and again. Just follow the code and the text and you will understand.

Comment: I am not blaming you, it is just really hard to follow

Comment: I built a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/6/ can you explain using this?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Ok. Please go to Order Related---->Request a Return/Exchange

You will some fields generated among which is a Select field with two options - Refund, Exchange

Now change Order Related to something else. This Select Field doesn't go away like it should when other options are selected.